# How session attributes can be access by Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've tryed to access the variable in this way:

```
<p th:text="${#session.getAttribute('mySessionAttribute')}"></p>

@RequestMapping({"/"})
String index(HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "someValue");
    return "index";
}
```

The documentation says: #session : direct access to the javax.servlet.http.HttpSession object associated with the current request.

I'm using Tomcat 8, Java 8, Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RivanLuiz [This](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects) is what you are looking for

Comment: The @Metroids answer fits better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.).

You can simply use `<p th:text="${session.mySessionAttribute}" />`